# Using parameter of method as a result holder as well

Tags: android

I am still in learning phase of android, I am comfortable with C language and hence tend to follow the same patterns in android as well. I want to understand this specific behavior which i observed in android (I was not able to find anything on google as answer).

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.picturePath);
imageBitmap =binarizingTheImage(imageBitmap); //binarizing the image
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);   //Still original image is displayed
```

Now my question is when we use **c = c+a;** , then the result does get updated in c variable.

But when i use the code above, i was expecting the binarized image to be displayed in imageView, but that was not the case. But when i use a diffrent variable as result holder i do get what i am expecting.

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.picturePath);
binarizedImage=binarizingTheImage(imageBitmap);  //Binarizing
+imageView.setImageBitmap(binarizedImage);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this type

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test2.png");
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: I am not looking for answer, but explanation of why that happens.